# jQuery Animation to Grow and shrink size issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Some thing gone wrong with my code, it's behaving strange. I have written a code, On hover a title width will be increased and fit to container width, with my code It is working, but if you hover in and hover out continuously the width of the title will grow and will not comeback to default width - i know confusing so I am giving the code right here...plz help

HTML

```
 <div class="cat-boxes">
                <img src="img/3.jpg" />
                <div class="cat-boxes-desc">
                    <span class="cat-title"><h3>culture and history</h3></span>
                    <p>
                        Festivals are true celebrations in God's Own Country
                    </p>
                    <a href="archive.html" class="articles">Articles</a>
                </div>
            </div><!--end cat-boxes-->
```

CSS

```
    .cat-boxes{
width:300px;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
background:#ecebeb;
float:left;
margin-bottom:25px;
}
.cat-boxes img{
width:100%;
}
.cat-boxes-desc{
width:234px;
height:115px;
padding:6px 15px;
position:relative;
z-index:999;
background:rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
margin: -25px auto 15px auto;
}
.cat-boxes-desc .cat-title{
display:inline-block;
padding:0 15px;
line-height:35px;
position:absolute;
top:-35px;
right:0;
background:#04a732;
}
.cat-boxes-desc .cat-title h3{
font-size:14px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height:35px;
text-align:center;
color:white;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-weight:normal;
margin:0;
}
.cat-boxes-desc p{
font: 14px Arial, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color:black;
line-height:20px;
text-transform:uppercase
}
```

jQuery

```
    $(function(){
$('.cat-boxes').hover(function(){
$wd = $(this).find($('.cat-title')).width();

$(this).find($('.cat-title')).stop().animate({ 
top: '-35px',
right: '-20px',
width:'105%',
'text-align':'center'
}, {duration: "slow"});
}, function(){

$(this).find($('.cat-title')).stop().animate({ 
top: '-35px',
right: '0px',
width: $wd
}, {duration: "slow"});

});
});
```

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

try this script

```
 $(function () {
        $('.cat-boxes').mouseover(function () {
            wd = $(this).find('.cat-title').width();

            $(this).find('.cat-title').stop().animate({
                top: '35px',
                right: '-20px',
                width: '105%',
                    'text-align': 'center'
            }, 'slow' );
        }).mouseout(function () {

            $(this).find('.cat-title').stop().animate({
                top: '-35px',
                right: '-40px',
                width: wd
            }, 'slow' );

        });
    });
```

jsfiddle for it
http://jsfiddle.net/wmMpN/

Comment: Brthr thanx for quick replay, I think that also not working, just try to move mouse back and forth on the div fast. you can see the '.cat-title' grows but not going back to initial width stored in 'wd' when you mouse out. thats wat the issue i said.